# How should I connect the TVS GND in a metal enclosure?

Tags: esd

I am using a TVS diode for ESD protection.  My device has a metal enclosure and I wonder if I should connect the TVS GND to the metal enclosure or system GND.

Comment: It depends on a lot of small details. Can you do a partial schematic and layout, by any chance? There are probably only two cases. Case 1, you are placing the TVS close to where the ESD occurs, and enclosure is bonded to Board ground at this location. Then connect to enclosure.

Case 2, you are worried about damaging a fragile input. Place it close to the input and ground near input.

Answer (score 0):

The GND of the electronics inside the enclosure. I assume you want protect a input signal ? Then the TVS should protect the signal for too high voltages relative the GND of the electronics. That needs protection.

The enclosure itself can be connected to that same GND, or via a resistor, sometimes via a RC circuit. Sometimes a resistor of 1M is used, to avoid static electricity build up.